# Defining Own Data Type in Haskell Where clause

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

```
data Geometry = Point {xCoord:: Double
                        ,yCoord:: Double} |Line  {xCoeff:: Double 
                      ,yCoeff:: Double
                       ,constant:: Double}|Plane {xCoeff:: Double,yCoeff:: Double, 
                       zCoeff::Double,
                       constant::Double} deriving (Show)

intersection:: Geometry -> Geometry -> Either String Geometry
intersection (Line a1 b1 c1) (Line a2 b2 c2)
                              | #### some code

intersection (Plane a1 b1 c1 d1) (Plane a2 b2 c2 d2)
                               | #### some code
                               | n1_n2_z /= 0 = Right $ParamerticLine (Point3D t1 (cond12/n1_n2_z) 0) (Point3D n1_n2_x n1_n2_y n1_n2_z)
                               | otherwise ## some code
                               where {Point t1 t2 = intersection (Line a1 b1 d1) (Line a2 b2 d2)}
```

I am trying to compute intersection of line in where clause of intersection of plane and using t1 in condition n1_n2_z/=0. I am getting error for where clause. Could I use intersection function as defined in where clause. What am I doing wrong in where clause?

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this fails, is because `intersect` has as signature:

```
intersection:: Geometry -> Geometry -> Either String Geometry
```

but the left side of your `where` clause says:

```
where Point t1 t2 = intersection (Line a1 b1 d1) (Line a2 b2 d2)
```

so here your left operand has as type a `Geometry`, not an `Either String Geometry`.

You should thu capture this as:

```
where Right (Point t1 t2) = intersection (Line a1 b1 d1) (Line a2 b2 d2)
```

But this is *unsafe*, since it might happen that this is a `Left "some error message". You thus might want to use a [*pattern guard* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard) here:

```
# …
intersection (Plane a1 b1 c1 d1) (Plane a2 b2 c2 d2)
    | … = …
    | n1_n2_z /= 0, Right (Point t1 t2) <- intersection (Line a1 b1 d1) (Line a2 b2 d2) = Right $ ParamerticLine (Point3D t1 (cond12/n1_n2_z) 0) (Point3D n1_n2_x n1_n2_y n1_n2_z)
    | otherwise = …
```

Or you could take a look to the `Monad (Either a)` implementation, and thus use the bind to work with such `Either a`.